# "Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'." in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm just creating a simple Spring MVC Hello world program and while I'm running it I always get this error again and again...

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 72; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using following jar files..

```
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
```

and this is my spring-servlet.xml file:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 
 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 
 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller">
         
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/">
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp">
    </property></property></property></bean>
</context:component-scan></beans>
```

I can't understand what is the problem with other similar question . Please help me to resolve this error..

Answer (score 3):

Your `spring-servlet.xml` isn't valid. The xml tags aren't closed properly. See below for the correct one.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"     xsi:schemalocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```